# Show execution time for every script that imports a specific module (without defining it inside the script)

Tags: python, python-3.x

so I have a lot (thousands of single scripts) that use the same library (self-developed) by importing *.

Is there a way for me to see/print the execution time for each script without modifying every single script, probably define at the library but expecting it to print before the code ends?

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a way.

I put this code inside the library.

```
class TestTimer:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.TimeStart = time.time()
    
    def __del__(self):
        print(f'Total TestTime: {time.time() - self.TimeStart}')

ExecutionTime = TestTimer()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't put time recording inside the library.

You will either have to put it inside each and every script.

May I ask how are you calling these 1000s of scripts? you can put the timer wherever it is you're calling these scripts from

Comment: It's some sort of test script. Every single script is run individually, for example if I want to check A, ill run A.py.

Comment: I actually found a way. Thank you for the input sir.